# How to match a column based on another one to fill a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'col1': ['a1','c3','b1','a2','','','',''],
        'col2': ['','', '','','','','',''],
        'col3': ['b1\\whatever', 'c1\\etc', 'a1\\something', 'a2\\random', 'a3\\somethingrandom', 'a4\\something','b2', 'b3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

  col1 col2                col3
0   a1              b1\whatever
1   c3                   c1\etc
2   b1             a1\something
3   a2                a2\random
4            a3\somethingrandom
5                  a4\something
6                            b2
7                            b3
```

I'd like to obtain :

```
  col1 col2                col3
0   a1   a1         b1\whatever
1   c3                   c1\etc
2   b1   b1        a1\something
3   a2   a2           a2\random
4            a3\somethingrandom
5                  a4\something
6                            b2
7                            b3
```

So I'd like to fill col2, based on if the value that matches is present in col1, and ignore whatever is after "\"
thank you

Comment: Please correct `a1\something'` and others, this is an invalid escape. Is the character a `\\`?

Comment: Also double check your output, col2 seems to just be a copy of col1

Comment: The escape character is corrected, but the result is the one desired, imagine it with more values, I want to find all values of col3 rhat equal col1 and to put them in col2 where it matches

Comment: Then the logic is unclear, how is `a2` matching `a1\\something` in the first row?

Comment: I don't want to change col3, just to fill col2 with the corresponding values if they are present in col3 and match col1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the values in col3 **globally**, first [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.extract.html) all leading values with the `^([^\\]+)` regex, then perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
valid = df['col3'].str.extract(r'^([^\\]+)', expand=False).unique()
# array(['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], dtype=object)

df.loc[df['col1'].isin(valid), 'col2'] = df['col1']
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2                col3
0   a1   a1         b1\whatever
1   c3                   c1\etc
2   b1   b1        a1\something
3   a2   a2           a2\random
4            a3\somethingrandom
5                  a4\something
6                            b2
7                            b3
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mSCq15/1)

Comment: this is not the desired output, I'd like to match the values of col3 (without the extra characters)  to the values of col1 and put them in col2 when they correspond

Comment: But here they don't correspond. Or do you want the match to be global, not row-wise? Can you give an example for which there would be no match?

Comment: I will edit my example sorry for the confusion

Comment: Then my current approach should be what you want

Comment: It is definetly the right approach ! it doesnt match a2 with my last example, would you know why?

Comment: It does for me, please make sure to use the example that I corrected (you had incorrect escapes). You can also try `r'^([^\\]+)'` as regex as it doesn't require the backslash to be present